# VIM Mapping doesn't work properly when I create macros

Tags: vim, mapping, vim-macros

I started studying VIM around 3 days ago. And now I'm stuck creating macros.

On the beginning of learning VIM I created mapping: **jk -> ESC** for convenience (`inoremap jk <ESC>`). Now my macros works correctly only if I pressed **ESC**; with **jk** they don't work properly.

For example I create macros to add `:` to the beginning and end of line:

```
'I' + ':' + 'ESC' + 'A' + ':' + 'ESC'
```

**@a macros:** I exited insert mode with `jk`.
**@b macros:** I exited insert mode with `<ESC>`.

If apply `@a` to the line `example`, I **don't** get the colon at the end... I
end up with:

```
:example
```

If apply `@b` to the line `example`, I **do** get the colon at the end... I end
up with:

```
:example:
```

Output of command - `:registers` (macros aren't the same):
[image]

`~/.vimrc` :

```
1 syntax on " highlight syntax 
2 set number " show line numbers
3 set hlsearch " highlight all results
4 set noswapfile " disable the swapfile
5 set ignorecase " ignore case in search
6 set incsearch " show search results as you type
7 " set spell spelllang=en_us " misspelled words are automatically underlined
8 
9 inoremap jk <ESC> " type 'jk' for leaving insert mode
```

Q: **How to make behavior of 'jk' and 'ESC' equal when recording macros.**

P.S.
Sorry if the explanation is not smooth, this is my first question and I tried to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Using `$ vim -Nu NONE` (without a config), both recordings result in `:example:`, here. How do you play back `@a` and `@b`, exactly?

Comment: @romainl I go to the line what I want to change and type `@a` or `@b` in normal mode.

Comment: Same method here. Can you try without your config?

Comment: But without config `jk` won't work. Btw, I don't use any plugins, only some commands in .vimrc (`syntax on; number; hlsearch; noswapfile; ignorecase; incsearch; inoremap jk <ESC>`)

Comment: 1. You can test your mapping on the command-line. 2. That `syntax on; number; hlsearch; noswapfile; ignorecase; incsearch; inoremap jk <ESC>` doesn't look like proper syntax. Can we add your `vimrc` to your question?

Comment: @romainl Thanks. The problem was in my `.vimrc`. My comment to inoremap was in the same line. When I moved the comment up, everything worked. Also the comment began to be highlighted I'll add the link to post that helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the comment up.

Instead of:

```
inoremap jk <ESC> " type 'jk' for leaving insert mode
```

Do:

```
" type 'jk' for leaving insert mode
inoremap jk <ESC>
```

Vim interprets this comment as part of your mapping.

See "[Why does remapping  make the cursor jump?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6922)" for additional information.